Why does the loop work and direct calculation does not?
I am trying to run a calculation on a Pandas Dataframe and don't understand why the direct calculation fails and the loop calculation works.  The direct calculation works if I remove the math.sqrt function.
a, b and c are float constants.
This line fails:
grid['Conf'] = (-b + math.sqrt(b*b-4.0*a*(c-grid['Distance'])))/(2.0*a)

The error is
--> 185 raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

But this works (incorrect results since the sqrt is removed):
grid['Conf'] = (-b + (b*b-4.0*a*(c-grid['Distance'])))/(2.0*a)

And this works (correct result but takes a long time to calculate):
for i in grid.index:
    grid['Conf'].iloc[i] = (-b + math.sqrt(b*b-4.0*a*(c-grid['Distance'].iloc[i])))/(2.0*a)


import numpy as np

The
math.sqrt()
function accepts a scalar and produces a scalar.
To operate on a numpy
array
of distances, you're looking for
np.sqrt().

Thanks for the reply.  numpy.sqrt worked.

Consider elaborating on this answer for posterity.

@ChukwujiobiCanon, thanks. I was viewing this question as "OP doesn't understand the signature, let's distinguish between scalar and array for him". But it sounds like you have some additional doubts or issues you're thinking of, which could be clarified in an improved answer. What's on your mind?

It had to do with scalars and arrays.  As I was setting up the calculation I used math.sqrt() and a single distance, not a dataframe/array of distances.  That worked fine.  Changing the single distance to a dataframe raised the error.  I'm still learning Python coming from a fortran background.  In Fortran, sqrt() works on both scalars and arrays.  Didn't occur to me that python would need np.sqrt() for an array.

numpy.sqrt worked
grid['Conf'] = (-b + numpy.sqrt(b*b-4.0*a*(c-grid['Distance'])))/(2.0*a)

